# Android VideoView cannot play video from some URL

Tags: android, android-videoview

```
String LINK = "my_url";
VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
mVideoView.start();
```

"http://benzeen.mn/media/a3638788-4a9f-4832-8861-cb9bae1b39e9/7c5961e5-a1bf-4f28-9aeb-2f70a0e79444.mp4". This URL of video is not playing with VideoView. Web browser can play this video successfully. I wrote the code above. Also I tried to use (WebView), but it couldn't load the video.

Answer (score 1):

```
    WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(view,true);
view.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    }
    view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
    view.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerentWebViewClient());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    view.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    }
    url = "YOUR URL";
    view.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        view.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        view.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        view.loadUrl("web_url");
```

Comment: setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture() this method failed. I use API16

Comment: leave this method

Comment: I ignored but it still not playing

Comment: can you share url .??

Comment: http://benzeen.mn/media/a3638788-4a9f-4832-8861-cb9bae1b39e9/7c5961e5-a1bf-4f28-9aeb-2f70a0e79444.mp4

Comment: Having the same issue with URL's from Azure.
However, I noticed that you'r container is MPEG-4 (QuickTime) Perhaps try changing the codec in your case to one android can play.